# Problem with mle function in R: Error: Mismatch in length of start values

Tags: mle

I am trying to use the mle function on a very simple task and I am getting the same mistake all over the times.

Even though my 'init_params' has length 2 as it is supposed to.

I tried to use the 'init_params' as a list and anything but still get the same results. I did follow the examples of the mle function (?mle) but still not understand how it works or at least where is my mistake.

````
library(stats4)

# Generate some data from an AR(1) process with a=1, b=0.8, and sigma=1
set.seed(123)
n <- 100
x <- numeric(n)
x[1] <- rnorm(1)
for (i in 2:n) {
  x[i] <- 1 + 0.8*x[i-1] + rnorm(1)
}

# Define the log-likelihood function for the AR(1) model
ar1_loglik <- function(params, data) {
  a <- params[1]
  b <- params[2]
  sigma <- params[3]
  n <- length(x)
  ll <- -n/2*log(2*pi*sigma^2) - sum((x-a-b*x[-1])^2)/(2*sigma^2)
  return(ll)
}

# Set initial parameter values and bounds for optimization
init_params <- c(mean(x), 0.5, sd(x))
lower_bounds <- c(-Inf, -1, 0)
upper_bounds <- c(Inf, 1, Inf)

# Maximize the log-likelihood using optimization
fit <- mle(ar1_loglik, start = init_params, nobs = n, 
           lower = lower_bounds, upper = upper_bounds, 
           method = "L-BFGS-B")```
 
#ERROR
Mismatch in length of start values
````